# PHP breaks when uploaded

Tags: php

Everything is looking great on my WAMP server, and the script works exactly as desired. When uploaded to server, it gives nothing, with just a white page as a result.

My host has php errors turned off so I'm left to wonder why this isn't happening.

EDIT: Added entire page code.

```
<?php
// When issuing a query "INSERT INTO users....", can use "NOW()" as a value to post "date entered" time, as well as "NULL" for UID to register auto incriment.

include_once("../ex/database.php"); //Includes a connection file.
include_once("../ex/defines.php");

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["sess_user"])){
    header("location:login.php");
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sermons | <?php print(COMPANY_name) ?></title>

<!-- INCLUDE STYLE SHEETS -->
    <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/MasterStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- INCLUDE HEAD PHP -->

<?php include("../ex/head.php")?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmation(){
    return window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete selected sermons? \nThis cannot be undone.");
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<header>
<?php include("inc/header.php")?>
</header>
<nav>
<?php include("inc/nav.php")?>
</nav>
<div class="content">
<p style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;text-align:center;"><a href="addSermon.php">Add New Sermon</a></p>
<?php

$seriesno = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM sermons WHERE series_id IS NULL");

echo "<table class='users'>
<form name='delete' method='post' action='".htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."'>
<tr>
  <th>Individual Sermons</th>
<tr>
<tr>
  <th style='width:200px;'>Sermon Name</th>
  <th style='width:150px;'>Preacher Name</th>
  <th style='width:200px;'>Series</th>
  <th style='width:100px;'>Date Preached</th>
  <th style='width:100px;'>Date Added</th>
  <th style='width:50px;'>Audio</th>
  <th style='width:50px;'>Delete</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($seriesno))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><a href='editSermon.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['sermon_name'] . "</a></td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['preacher'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['series_id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['date_preached'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['date_added'] . "</td>";
  if($row['audio_file']!==NULL){
      echo "<td>" . $row['audio_file'] . "</td>";
  } else {
      echo "<td>N/A</td>";
  }
  echo "<td><input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' id='checkbox[]' value='" . $row['id'] . "'></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td></td>";
  echo "<td></td>";
  echo "<td></td>";
  echo "<td></td>";
  echo "<td></td>";


  echo "<td><input name='delete' type='submit' id='delete' value='Delete' onclick='return confirmation()'></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";

$seriesres = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM sermons WHERE series_id IS NOT NULL ORDER BY series_id DESC");

echo "<table class='users'>
<tr>
  <th>Sermon Series</th>
<tr>
<tr>
  <th style='width:200px;'>Sermon Name</th>
  <th style='width:150px;'>Preacher Name</th>
  <th style='width:200px;'>Series</th>
  <th style='width:100px;'>Date Preached</th>
  <th style='width:100px;'>Date Added</th>
  <th style='width:50px;'>Audio</th>
  <th style='width:50px;'>Delete</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($seriesres))
{
    //<a href='editSermon.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>Edit User</a>
    //<a href='removeSermon.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "' onclick='return confirmation()'>Delete User</a>
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><a href='editSermon.php?id=" . $srow['id'] . "'>" . $srow['sermon_name'] . "</a></td>";
  echo "<td>" . $srow['preacher'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $srow['series_id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $srow['date_preached'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $srow['date_added'] . "</td>";
  if($srow['audio_file']!==NULL){
      echo "<td>" . $srow['audio_file'] . "</td>";
  } else {
      echo "<td>N/A</td>";
  }
  echo "<td></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td></td>";
  echo "<td></td>";
  echo "<td></td>";
  echo "<td></td>";
  echo "<td></td>";
  echo "<td><input name='delete' type='submit' id='delete' value='Delete' onclick='return confirmation()'></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
echo "</form></table>";
?>
</div>
<span class="bottom">Logged in as <?=$_SESSION['sess_user'];?>. <a href="logout.php">Logout</a></span>

</body>
</html>

<?php 

if(!isset($_POST['delete'])){
    echo "Try";
}
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
// If delete button is pressed...
 if (count($_POST['checkbox']) > 0) {
   foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $del_id) {
    $delsql = "DELETE FROM sermons WHERE id=' " . $del_id . " ' ";
    $delres = mysqli_query($conn, $delsql);
    if($row['audio_file']!==NULL){
//    unlink($row['audio_file']);
//      } else {
//    echo "Attached file could not be deleted. Make sure you delete ".$row['audio_file']." manually!";
    }
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0){
        header: ("location:index.php");
    } else {echo "nope";}
  }
 } else {echo "nope";}
} else {echo "nope";}


?>
```

This is supposed to delete all rows with a checked "checkbox."
I'm using this for the each checkbox if that helps...

The PHP version on my server is 5.2.17

My current WAMP version is 5.5.12

I can't imagine it being the version but it's the only difference I can imagine between the two locations.

Does anyone see anything else? If it is the version, any ideas on how to make it compatible with the previous version?

Comment: Most likely it's hitting your first condition, and it may be a get request you are trying to process. Why not try to echo something in the first condition?
if(!isset($_POST['delete']) ){
  echo "No good";
}

Comment: Check error.log on server or enable display of errors. `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: please tell me that isn't just open to anyone and everyone POSTing to your page. That said, you can reenable errors and warnings for just your script with `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Add it to before where you suspect things go wrong, and if there's error output, add it to the post

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the beginning of your script and you should see what error is happening.

Comment: @ Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans ... I'm not that nooby haha, this is an admin panel script that only established administrators have access to. :)

Comment: Tried adding the error reporting... Still comes up blank.

Comment: Echo in the first condition comes back blank too.

Comment: Keep in mind that an empty checkbox sends nothing to post. So does this blank screen still happen when you check one of the checkboxes? - also, it couldn't hurt to post the html.

Comment: Added entire source code. I can't imagine it being the checkboxes, because 1. They don't appear at all when the page loads on the sever, and 2. The script runs without problem nor error on WAMP